# Sprite Changes size when flipped in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and unity. I added flipping sprite in my simple running game. But when it flips side, it automatically changes it's size. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayeMoveLol : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D body;
    Vector3 scale = new Vector3( 3, 3, 1f );
    private Animator anim;

    private void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontalinput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalinput * speed, body.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, speed / 3);
        }
        if (horizontalinput > 0.01f) {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        }
        if (horizontalinput < -0.01f) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }
        anim.SetBool("running", horizontalinput != 0);
        transform.localScale = scale;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: in general when using physics instead of using the `transform.localScale` you should rather use the [`SpriteRenderer.flipX`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html)

Comment: And then I don't understand your logic ... you have certain conditions for setting a hardcoded scale of `(1,1,1)` or `-1,1,1` ... but either way no matter what you anyway overwrite it with `transform.localScale = scale;` so the input doesn't matter at all for the scaling

Comment: Forgot to mention:  I was following a tutorial. I followed him on every step but i was using different sprites and stuff. I will try what derHugo said me to use